# Set Node.js to use a local HTTP/SOCKS proxy for all outgoing requests?

Tags: windows, node.js, proxy, firewall

I am using Node.js on Windows, and unfortunately had to pipe all outbound traffic through a corporate proxy (HTTP/SOCKS) to test any outgoing requests (for example, oauth, where node.js must reach remote server for tokens).

Is there a global configuration where I can specify this? I don't think it's worth it to update oauth module to support proxy; our production environment does not require such proxy configuration anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override node.js http to use a proxy for all outbound requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442985/how-to-override-node-js-http-to-use-a-proxy-for-all-outbound-requests)