# How do I add proxy in NodeJs for outbound calls

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have a function app deployed on Azure.

My requirement is to call another API internal to the organization.

But all the traffic has to be routed through a proxy server setup on prem. How do I tell my NodeJs code, to make the outbound request using a proxy server.

I did set the http and https proxy in node runtime using npm set commands, that seems to have no effect.

I am seeing host not found errors. To both the proxy server and the actual api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override node.js http to use a proxy for all outbound requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442985/how-to-override-node-js-http-to-use-a-proxy-for-all-outbound-requests)

Comment: [How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use an http proxy with node.js http.Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862813/how-can-i-use-an-http-proxy-with-node-js-http-client)

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the code to add proxy for Azure functions*

```js
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: "proxy",
  port: 8080,
  path: "http://www.google.com",
  headers: {
    Host: "www.google.com"
  }
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

*For more information you can refer the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6781592/15969833)*